# Is there a way to see which entities are being accessed in Appstats?

Tags: google-app-engine, appstats

While analyzing Appstats traces for `datastore_v3.Get` calls, it would be very helpful to know which entities are being retrieved from the datastore. Is there a hidden configuration flag that enables this?

I have tried setting `appstats_DATASTORE_DETAILS` to `True` in `appengine_config.py`, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no hidden configuration flag to do that. The sources of the Appstats module are open.

You can view them at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fpython%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine%2Fext%2Fappstats (python version) and https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fjava%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine%2Ftools%2Fappstats (java version).

You can search there to see if there is already something like that or you can copy the code and make the changes yourself. You can even send back a patch with changes that can be integrated into the sdk.